# Min/Max Aggregate over Window based on Conditional Row Values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sample data in SQL Server below:

```
drop table if exists #test;
create table #test (id char(4), product char(1), inception date, salary int, grp_start bit, grp_end bit);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2003-03-01', 125000,1,0);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2004-03-01', 150000,0,0);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2005-03-01', 300000,0,0);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2006-03-01', 400000,0,1);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'L', '2016-03-01', 500000,1,0);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'L', '2016-10-01', 450000,0,1);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2018-10-01', 130000,1,0);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2020-03-01', 150000,0,1);
```

[image]

I'd like to group this data based on `grp_start` and `grp_end` and run an aggregate function over it like `min()`

I'm probably overcomplicating this, but I'd like to find a way to create a dynamic window that would encapsulate rows 1-4, rows 5-6 and rows 7-8 and take the minimum `salary` in the group. The window groups are marked appropriately.

My intuition wanted to try a `min(salary) over (partition by product, id order by inception)` or a rolling sum total that essentially aggregates these "groups" up until the value in each group is = 2. `grp_start + grp_end = 2` for each group (1 for the grp_start and 1 for the grp_end). I'm just not sure how to go about doing it.

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: Does the table have a column which will define the order ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha yeah, sorry about that. Didn't add it to the table. I updated my test data SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with adding group start and end, but I think ranking the salaries within the group and selecting the row with the lowest rank is the best way to implement it.

```
create table #test (id char(4), product char(1), inception date, salary int, grp_start bit, grp_end bit);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2003-03-01', 125000,1,0);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2004-03-01', 150000,0,0);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2005-03-01', 300000,0,0);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2006-03-01', 400000,0,1);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'L', '2016-03-01', 500000,1,0);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'L', '2016-10-01', 450000,0,1);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2018-10-01', 130000,1,0);
insert into #test (id, product,  inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end) values('0001', 'T', '2020-03-01', 150000,0,1);

    with ctePre as (
        SELECT *
            , SUM(CONVERT(INT, grp_start) + CONVERT(INT,grp_end)) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY inception 
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Grp
        FROM #test 
    ), cteGrouped as (
        SELECT id, product, inception, salary, grp_start, grp_end
            , grp, floor((Grp + 1) /2) as grpFinal
        FROM ctePre as  P
    ), cteSorted as (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, grpFinal ORDER BY Salary) as SalRank
        FROM cteGrouped as G
    )
    SELECT id, product, inception, salary
    FROM cteSorted as S
    WHERE SalRank = 1
    
    drop table #test;
```

gives results

| id | product | inception | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | T | 2003-03-01 | 125000 |
| 0001 | L | 2016-10-01 | 450000 |
| 0001 | T | 2018-10-01 | 130000 |

Comment: This is great! Works like a charm. Can you explain the logic on the floor( (grp + 1) / 2) part? The rest makes sense! Thanks

Comment: Sure @Coldchain9, if you consider the start bit and end bit as as integers, the running total of the sum will start at 1 at the beginning of the first block, go to 2 at the end of the first block, 3 at the start of the second block, 4 at the end of the second block, etc. but we want the whole block to have the same number. So if X starts at 1, then (X+1)/2 rounded down will be 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 ... which is the behavior we want. Note that rows with neither start nor end bits won't affect the total. Also note that the SUM is partitioned by ID, so start and end for one ID won't affect other IDs.

Answer (score 1):

```
I offer my solution.I only use row_number to create the groups.
I hope it helps.

with data as (
select *,row_number()over(order by inception)-row_number()over(partition by product order by inception)as rn 
from #test)
select id, product, min(salary)as min_salary
from data
group by id, product, rn
order by 3;
```